# Why are both gradient of loglikelihood objective and mean squared error of regression the same?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, gradient, logistic-regression

The gradients of the logistic regression model when you use log-likelihood(cross entropy) as your objective function and the gradients of the linear regression model when you take mean squared error as your object function are the same. Is that a coincidence?

Comment: those gradients aren't the same

Comment: Really?The expression for logistic regression is: pred=1/(1+exp(-wx-b)),the object function is -y*log(pred)-(1-y)log(1-p
red), the gradient is :dw = (y-pred)*x also for regression ,pred = wx+b, the object function is (y-pred)^2, the gradient is also dw = (y-pred)*x
?How are they not the same?

Comment: writing in this way you can say many functions are the same, but  `pred`'s are different in these two cases (so expressions are *different*). Gradients are different in their fundamental properties: (y-pred) is bounded in first case, and ubbounded in the second. 

Treat your observation as coincidence, nothing deep here.

Answer (score 0):

When you are optimizing the log likelihood of a logistic classifier model, you are in fact optimizing the mean squared error between the model and the target. That is why you take the log. It is to linearize the binomial distribution and when you take the cross entropy, you effectively get the MSE.

However, the same is not true for complex models such as a Neural Network where the target could be of any distribution and not necessarily a Gaussian.

Tldr: When the target model is Gaussian, MSE is basically optimizing cross entropy but when the target model gets complex, using MSE will still assume that your target model is a Gaussian one while cross entropy will try to approximate a more complex distribution of the data